# How to stop downloads from being organized by date?

Tags: finder, safari, data-transfer

Many moons ago I installed an application that moves downloads into a desktop folder with today's date as the title. I would like to stop this behavior.

However, I cannot remember what I did to cause this behavior.

Specs:

- 10.7.x
- Mac Pro.

Things I've tried:

- I checked System Preferences and Activity Monitor, and see nothing
  obvious.
- I made a separate test user account, and this behavior does not occur
  in this account.

Any other ideas what to look for to get rid of this, would be most welcome.

Comment: Did u install the Glims for the Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the answer should be the Glims.  Either uninstall the Glims, or config the GLims not to organize the downloading into dated folder.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the voting power to thank you properly, but really appreciate the effort in helping.

Answer (score 0):

I have a two places for you to look...maybe one hits

- Look for a folder action on the downloads folder (right click on it and see if there is anything at the bottom of the list)  You may have used automator to do this
- Are you running Hazel?  Check system preferences to see if it is installed